# Replace with multiple spaces starting a string with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the input in /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 fake.hostname.net   fake
```

I want to replace the second `fake` with `real`. The following sed statement attempts to filter the two apart by matching two spaces before, but it does nothing:

```
sed -i -e 's/  fake/  new/g' /etc/hosts
```

Result is:

```
127.0.0.1 fake.hostname.net   fake
```

Expected result is:

```
127.0.0.1 fake.hostname.net   new
```

I have also tried the following with the same results:

```
sed -i -e 's/\s\sfake/\s\snew/g' /etc/hosts
```

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it? I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 Server. I do not wish to simply replace the second match, as I am expecting things like:

```
127.0.0.1 asdf.hostname.net   fake
```

as well, so the space matching is the only acceptable method.

```
echo "127.0.0.1 fake.hostname.net   fake" | sed -e 's/  fake/  new/g'
```

Returns the expected result, but the same statement does not write to the file. Simply not putting the extra spaces in the statement writes to the file, so it's not a filesystem permissions issue.

Comment: can you confirm that the expression works as expected if you use `cat`: `cat /etc/hosts | sed -e 's/  fake/  new/g'`? also, confirm that the whitespace is, in fact, spaces, not tabs?

Comment: @WilliBallenthin It does: `echo "127.0.0.1 fake.hostname.net   fake" | sed -e 's/  fake/  new/g'` and yes, it's spaces, not tabs. If I don't put the spaces in the expression, the file updates, so it's not a permissions issue. Stack Overflow is nuking the double space even in code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
sed -i 's/fake$/real$/' /etc/hosts
```

`$` matches the end of the line. You don't need the `g` option since there is only one match per line.

Comment: That solved my problem, thanks. I'm still wondering about the space behavior, however.

Comment: probably it was a `tab`?

Comment: I'm certain it was a space, even ran it through a hex dump.

Comment: This will replace fake in `127.0.0.1 fake` but that might not cause any problems.